# Radially Iterating from a given point in a Cartesian Grid

Tags: python

Assuming I have a point (i, j) which are the indices of some maximum point in a 2D grid, I am trying to figure out how to get points of approximate constant radius and iterate through them. Effectively, I am currently doing a cartesian cluster algorithm, but I know the clusters are circular or at least elliptical,

An example of this grid could be

```
im = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
       [0,0,1,2,2,2,1,0,0],
       [0,1,2,3,3,3,1,1,0],
       [0,1,2,3,4,3,2,1,0],
       [0,1,3,5,5,5,3,1,0],
       [0,1,3,7,9,7,3,1,0],
       [0,1,2,3,5,3,2,1,0],
       [0,0,1,2,2,2,1,0,0],
       [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

Though in my application, these grids are variable in size. And the internal points could be any shape. This is a comparatively 'nice' example, because it is more circular. The zero points describe the exterior of the 'cluster'

```
im = some 2x2 grid

 ind = lambda i, j: ((i + 1, j + 1), (i - 1, j + 1), (i + 1, j - 1), (i - 1, j - 1), (
        i, j + 1), (i, j - 1), (i + 1, j), (i - 1, j))

maxij = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(im), np.array(im).shape)
i, j = maxij[0], maxij[1]
counts_out = [im[i][j]]
im[i][j] = 0
index_list = [(i, j)] #the point I want to iterate from within the grid
while True:
    current_counts = []
    cind = index_list.copy()
    index_list = []
    for (ip, jp) in cind:
        indlst = ind(ip, jp)
        for (ik, jk) in indlst:
            try:
                if im[ik][jk] > 0:
                    current_counts.append(im[ik][jk])
                    im[ik][jk] = 0
                    index_list.append((ik, jk))
            except IndexError:
                pass
     counts_out.append(sum(current_counts))
     if len(index_list) == 0:
         break
```

My current algorithm has an output, `counts_out`, if I start at grid point 9, of

```
counts_out = [9, 40, 47, 22, 8, 0]
```

I would ideally like this to sample approximate 'circular' boxes around the initial point. I am not sure exactly what the output of this would be.

Comment: Can you please (1) fix the indentation of the code and (2) show a small, but representative example of inputs and expected output?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I have added more detail, I'm not sure exactly what the output 'should' be, just that the points should be sampled at approximately constant radius. I have an example input and expected output. The issue is that the grid sizes sometimes extend to upwards of 100x100, with definite non circular shape with uneven edges so I need a cluster counting algorithm to sample all of the points.